# How to show/hide a cell based on a specific option being selected in a dropdown form element?

Tags: jquery, forms, animation

I have a form which has a "how did you hear about us?" section. The user can select different options from a dropdown form element. If the user selects "other" I want a text box to show allowing the user to specify. This whole form is in a table format, and that is not about to change, so I guess the easiest approach would be to show/hide a cell, but I have no idea how to connect that to a specific option being selected. I am using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching a function to the onchange event for the select (using [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)) that checks the select's value (using [val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)) and then hides/shows the text box accordingly (using [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) or [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myselectbox').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()=='other') {
        $('#othertextbox').show();
    } else {
        $('#othertextbox').hide();
    }
});
```